# Problem with bean instantiation using @Repository micronaut data annotation

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data, micronaut-rest

I'm approaching Micronaut framework to create a program to interact with a database.
I'm new to gradle project configuration etc. so it could be a problem related to this.

I divided my project in two modules: main(where the Application class is) and masterdata (where all the project is located)

In the "masterdata" module I have:

- one controller with a "/test" method that simply returns a string.

```
    package core.masterdata.module.controllers;
    
    import core.masterdata.module.entities.Person;
    import core.masterdata.module.repositories.PersonRepository;
    import core.masterdata.module.services.PersonService;
    import io.micronaut.core.version.annotation.Version;
    import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
    import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
    import jakarta.inject.Inject;
    
    import java.util.Optional;
    
    import static core.masterdata.module.constants.EntitiesConstants.BASE_URL;
    
    @Controller(BASE_URL + "/person/")
    @Version("1")
    public class PersonController {
    
        @Inject
        PersonService personService;
    
        @Inject
        PersonRepository personRepository;
    
        @Get("test")
        public String getPerson(Long pId){
            return "test";
        }
    }
```

- One repository:

```
package core.masterdata.module.repositories;

import core.masterdata.module.entities.Person;
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Repository;
import io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<**Person**, Long> {
}
```

- One entity class:

```
   package core.masterdata.module.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Person() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and one other class (empty) with @Singleton annotation

The project builds and compiles just fine but I get a runtime error if I inject the repository in the controller or in the service when I try to call the API.

I injected the @Singleton class as well in the controller class and it causes no problems at runtime. If I inject the repository in the empty class and then itself in the controller I get the error as well.

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Stack Trace:

```
Unexpected error occurred: Error instantiating bean of type  [core.masterdata.module.controllers.PersonController]

Message: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry, io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry]
Path Taken: new PersonController() --> PersonController.personRepository
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [core.masterdata.module.controllers.PersonController]

Message: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry, io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry]
Path Taken: new PersonController() --> PersonController.personRepository
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2363)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:3281)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:3267)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2820)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2782)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1638)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2035)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForField(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1579)
        at core.masterdata.module.controllers.$PersonController$Definition.injectBean(Unknown Source)
        at core.masterdata.module.controllers.$PersonController$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2336)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:3281)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:3267)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2820)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.access$100(DefaultBeanContext.java:151)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$4.getTarget(DefaultBeanContext.java:540)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$4.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:583)
        at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:303)
        at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:111)
        at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:103)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.RouteExecutor.lambda$executeRoute$14(RouteExecutor.java:659)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDeferContextual.subscribe(FluxDeferContextual.java:49)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:426)
        at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onNext(ReactorSubscriber.java:57)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371)
        at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onSubscribe(ReactorSubscriber.java:50)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust.subscribe(FluxJust.java:68)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.handleRouteMatch(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:586)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:449)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:102)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:224)
        at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:134)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.channelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:99)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.channelRead(HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.java:64)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.dequeue(FlowControlHandler.java:200)
        at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.channelRead(FlowControlHandler.java:162)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NonUniqueBeanException: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry, io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry]
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findConcreteCandidate(DefaultBeanContext.java:2429)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.findConcreteCandidate(DefaultApplicationContext.java:455)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.lastChanceResolve(DefaultBeanContext.java:3253)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findConcreteCandidateNoCache(DefaultBeanContext.java:3140)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findConcreteCandidate(DefaultBeanContext.java:3054)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2750)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:888)
        at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.resolveInterceptors(InterceptorChain.java:205)
        at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.resolveIntroductionInterceptors(InterceptorChain.java:144)
        at core.masterdata.module.repositories.PersonRepository$Intercepted.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at core.masterdata.module.repositories.$PersonRepository$Intercepted$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2336)
        ... 97 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I have 3 build.gradle files.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have misconfigured the Gradle build and you have multiple `micronaut-core` dependencies on the classpath.

Comment: https://github.com/Ale9600/testMicronauts here's the project on git. The current version of configuration is on test branch. I have looked for the problem but i can't find it :(

Comment: Probably you have defined Micronaut Data is some other version than the other ones. Try to eliminate allprojects block and just define micronaut gradle plugin in all subprojects.